# Dynamically show/hide columns in Gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm attempting to show/hide columns in gridview for better viewing.
What I need to do is:

1. hide columns 8, 9 and 10 on page load
2. show them upon button click

I successfully hidden them on pageload using RowCreated Event (code below). but as of now, I haven't yet found a way to show them again via button click.

```
  Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated

    Dim row As GridViewRow = e.Row
    ' Intitialize TableCell list
    Dim columns As New List(Of TableCell)()
    For Each column As DataControlField In GridView1.Columns
        'Get the first Cell /Column
        Dim cell As TableCell = row.Cells(0)
        ' Then Remove it after
        row.Cells.Remove(cell)
        'And Add it to the List Collections
        columns.Add(cell)
    Next

    ' Add cells
    row.Cells.AddRange(columns.ToArray())

    e.Row.Cells(8).Visible = False
    e.Row.Cells(9).Visible = False
    e.Row.Cells(10).Visible = False
    e.Row.Cells(11).Visible = False
End Sub
```

I tried the following methods with unfortunate results:

1. **Set width to 0px then reset to auto upon click**- since most of my columns are itemfields that contains either button or checkbox, this doesn't work at all
2. **Use GridView1.Columns(8).Visible = False** - same reason as above
3. Create RowDataBound Event with **e.Row.Cells(8).Visible = True** but i can't successfully call this event via button click yet.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the markup for your Gridview as well - it will enable us to provide a specific answer to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridView1.Columns(n).Visible = False` ' working in vb.net

where n represent the column index

Comment: thanks! i also learned that its very important to put the gridview inside an update panel or it won't work. :)

Comment: you can load data to grid or maintain data in the grid without post-back the page while using update pannel